# How do I fetch/read custom document properties using OfficeJs in a task pane app?

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office-js

I have added custom document property "TemplateId" from server and in task pane app when the document opens I want to fetch this [custom document property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrbtX.png) (see image) using OfficeJs.

(using OfficeJs version 1.1)

Comment: Which Office application? Word? Excel? PowerPoint? Which version of Office? 2013? 2016?

Comment: @CindyMeister Word 2016 - task pane app

Comment: Ater trying it out, I see that Gab's answer is correct - my bad. OOXML provides many things not available in the APIs, but custom document properties are not returned. Nor are they available through the CustomXMLParts API.

Comment: Thanks for for the confirmation @CindyMeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently no OfficeJS APIs that allows you to read custom document properties. However, feel free to request one on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: This is no longer true. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788002/word-add-in-how-to-read-custom-document-property