# Get Document Properties in Office Add-In

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, office-js

Is it possible to get and set document properties in an Office add-in written in JavaScript? I have a document in SharePoint which has a Content Type with some properties that each document with that content type have. I want the possibility to change these properties within word/excel/powerpoint.

Previously this was possible with a Document Information Panel. This was removed in Office 2016. Instead one should you the Properties panel available backstage. This is not a very good solution and I'm looking for a way to move from a Document Information Panel to a custom javascript add-in.

Comment: This question has been answered previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018412/how-do-i-fetch-read-custom-document-properties-using-officejs-in-a-task-pane-app

Comment: @Cindy Meister: this isn't quite the same question, assuming it is about properties set in SharePoint columns (represented by MetaProperties in Word), and not Built-in or old-style custom document properties. SharePoint metadata values *are* in the CustomXmlPart data and are in principle retrievable, although it's not very straightforward - there is some VBA code at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/set-default-filename-from-dip-values/1741650d-0c7d-4ed7-95ba-b2fe212f27aa?page=3

Comment: This is not a duplicated question - as it relates to SharePoint column added to document through content type (not custom document property)

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time.

Who knows what they might announce at Build this week ;)