# Word Add-in - How to read custom document property

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am developing a Word plugin using the Office JS API.

Currently I can add custom properties to the Word document by doing:

```
context.document.properties.load();
context.document.properties.customProperties.add("file-name-prop", "my file name");
```

If I then download the file I can see the property in the "custom.xml" file inside the zipped docx.

But I am not able to read the property back.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
context.document.properties.load();
var filenameProp = context.document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject("file-name-prop");
if (filenameProp) {
    // use filenameProp.value
} else {
    // ignore, property not set
}
```

When doing that, I am getting the following error:

```
code : "PropertyNotLoaded"
message : "The property 'type' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."
name : "OfficeExtension.Error"
```

Which would be the right way to read the property back?

(I am using this office js: `appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you didn't include the parts of your code, but I don't see anywhere you sync context. The error message you have provided indicates the same: "*Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.*". Looks like you are missing `context.sync()` at all or partially. You should be able to get custom properties after the context is synced. For example to create custom property the code should look similar to ...

```js
function setProperty (prop_name, prop_value) {
  Word.run(function (context) {
    context.document.properties.customProperties.add(prop_name, prop_value);
    return context.sync()
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      })
  })
}
```

And when you need to get a property the code is still uses "sync" to make property available. For example to get custom property the code should look similar to ...

```
function getProperties() { 
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var customDocProps = context.document.properties.customProperties;
        context.load(customDocProps);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(customDocProps.items.length);
             })
     })
}
```

Comment: Your answer was right, but in order to actually read the property value, I had to also make the context "load" the actual property. I am posting that as a separate answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Slava's answer is right, but to actually read the property value, I had to actually load that one as well, which I find quite convoluted, but well...

Final working code (borrowing Slava's sample):

```
function getPropertyValue() { 
  Word.run(function (context) {
    var customDocProps = context.document.properties.customProperties;
    // first, load custom properties object
    context.load(customDocProps);
    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
        console.log(customDocProps.items.length);
        // now load actual property
        var filenameProp = customDocProps.getItemOrNullObject("file-name-prop");
        context.load(filenameProp);
        return context.sync()
          .then(function () {
            console.log(filenameProp.value);
          });
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: only one sync is needed for a single property https://stackoverflow.com/a/42398350/1383168